# multiple constructors and class inheritance in F#

Tags: f#

I am having difficulty to convert following C# code to F#:

```cs
class Foo
{
    public Foo() { }
    public Foo(string name) { }
}

class Bar : Foo
{
    public Bar() : base() { }
    public Bar(string name) : base(name) { }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I first tried following, but it is reporting error

> Constructors for the type 'Bar' must directly or indirectly call its
>   implicit object constructor. Use a call to the implicit object
>   constructor instead of a record expression.

```
type Foo() =
    new(name:string) = Foo()

type Bar() =
    inherit Foo()
    new(name:string) = { inherit Foo(name) }
    member val Name:string = null with get, set
```

Then I tried following, but it is now reporting error on the auto property

> 'member val' definitions are only permitted in types with a primary
>   constructor. Consider adding arguments to your type definition"

```
type Foo() =
    new(name:string) = Foo()

type Bar =
    inherit Foo
    new(name:string) = { inherit Foo(name) }
    member val Name:string = null with get, set
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want F# source code who compiles to *precisely the same* API as given by your C# code, the answer is as follows:

```
type Foo =
    new() = {}
    new(name:string) = { }

type Bar =
    inherit Foo

    [<DefaultValue>] 
    val mutable private name:string

    new() = { inherit Foo() }
    new(name) = { inherit Foo(name) }

    member x.Name with get() = x.name and set v = x.name <- v
```

Comment: In this case you are still not able to add following:    member val Name = null with get,set

Comment: Yes, I oversaw that. I have edited the Bar class to include a Name property. It's not an auto-property, but the API and semantics are exactly the same as in the C# case. There is no other way of reproducing your C# example "to the letter".

Comment: Agree; this is the closest workaround at current moment.

Comment: I was getting the following compiler error: `No constructors are available for the type 'Foo'`. The fix was `new() = { inherit Foo() }`

Comment: @DharmaTurtle: Glad it works now for you; FYI, the line you are mentioning already existed in the answer.

Comment: @MarcSigrist - Sorry, the reason I left my comment was so googlers could more easily find your excellent answer =)

Answer (score 2):

This compiles:

```
type Foo() =
    new(name:string) = Foo()

type Bar(name : string) =
    inherit Foo()
    new() = Bar(null) // or whatever you want as a default.
    member val Name:string = name with get, set
```

See *[Constructors (F#)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233192.aspx)* and *[Inheritance (F#)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233225.aspx)*.

Looking at the decompilation, the C# would be (with attributes removed):

```cs
public class Bar : Program.Foo {
    internal string Name@;

    public string Name {
        get {
            return this.Name@;
        }
        set {
            this.Name@ = value;
        }
    }

    public Bar(string name) {
        this.Name@ = name;
    }

    public Bar() : this(null) {
    }
}

public class Foo {
    public Foo() {
    }

    public Foo(string name) : this() {
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks; but this is no longer the same C# code, right? I understand the example C# code isn't real code but the point is to see if we can have exact logic implemented in F#... I will accept yours as answer in a few days if there are no other good alternatives to this problem.

Comment: It is indeed not quite the same (`Bar.Name` is given a value from the `string` taking constructor), but – IMO – makes more sense (even more would be if the `Name` property was in the base type). And of cour5se, some of the difference is disassembled IL shows the implementation detail of the field.

Answer (score 1):

If a class has a parameter list directly after its name (including `()`), it has a *primary constructor*. Using it, any `inherit` declarations are placed only in this primary constructor, which comes directly after the class declaration and before any `member` declarations.

It is unclear what you are trying to achieve. The class `Foo` has a constructor taking a string argument, only to discard it. A (technically) valid, similar pair of classes would be this:

```
type Foo(name:string) =
    member f.NameLength = name.Length

type Bar(initialName) = // WARNING: this will not end well
    inherit Foo(initialName)
    member val Name:string = initialName with get, set
```

*But this is not sensible code.* `Foo` will keep the initial name even if the name in `Bar` is changed. `Bar.Name.Length` returns the current name's length, while `Bar.NameLength` returns the initial name's length.

To keep the default constructor, one could add `new () = Bar(null)` (or the equivalent in `Foo`), but please note that **null is considered an interop-only feature**. It is not used in F# facing code; if possible, use the appropriate option type or an empty string respectively (depending on whether the string is just empty or doesn't exist at all).

Also, inheriting classes is discouraged in the F# component design guidelines -- for good reason. There are few use cases, but those usually involve a tiny base class and a derived class that is a perfect superset of it. It is far more common to compose types by using one class as a member of another.

---

I don't know how relevant this is, but here is an example of a class with default constructor and an additional constructor that uses it:

```
type Text500(text : string) =
    do if text.Length > 500 then
        invalidArg "text" "Text of this type cannot have a length above 500."
    member t.Text = text
    new () = Text500("")
```

This utilizes the primary constructor to verify input and has an additional, parameterless constructor that uses an empty string. (I'm not sure if the additional constructor would be useful in actual applications.)

Comment: I'm trying to work with WPF and I suspect the empty constructor here would help with that.